# how to tell mod_deflate is disabled in apache?

Tags: apache, gzip, mod-deflate

Is there a line for .htaccess that can tell mod_deflate is disabled on Apache?
Something like this:

```
<!IfModule mod_deflate.c>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there with the exclamation point.

The correct syntax is `<IfModule !mod_deflate.c>`

Further info: [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#ifmodule).